# How can I add or remove elements to/from a WebStorm UML diagram

Tags: javascript, ide, webstorm, diagram

I'm using the [WebStorm Diagram generator](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/module-dependency-diagram.html) (select a set of files, right click, diagrams, show diagram), but have a couple of usability questions.

1. How can I delete or hide nodes/edges that I want to ignore?
2. How can I add/include another file to this diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible, please vote for [WEB-35506](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35506) to be notified on any progress with this feature